# How to make a 3 sided shadow for a box?

Tags: html, css

I tried a lot to a 4 sided shadow to make it as 3 sides and not getting any idea how it can be done. found one question from Stack for top and bottom for shadow but that did not help me well. 
I have given below the example of a shadow which is 4 sided and I need to know how is it possible to remove one side of the shadows specifically LEFT. Is it possible?

`0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);`

Comment: This question won't be well received because it doesn't conform to [mcve], please read [ask] before asking.

Comment: @DanBeaulieu ok im sorry i didn't check all those. After reading this you did not understand what i meant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve a simple shadow on 3 sides of an element by overlapping 2 shadows using `box-shadow`:

```
box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 0 #999, 3px -3px 3px 0 #999;  /* No shadow on the left */
```

This basically adds 2 shadows together to get the desired effect (I'm going to call this a Shadow Equation):

```
               _____        _____
       |   +        |   =        |
  _____|            |       _____|
```

### Why it works

The syntax for this CSS property is: `box-shadow: offset-x | offset-y | blur-radius | spread-radius | color`. By overlapping multiple shadows that have different offsets (starting positions), you can control which sides of the element the shadow appears on.

`box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 0 #999` creates a shadow that has an offset of 3px to the *right* and 3px *down* from the top, so the shadow will show on the *right* and *bottom* sides of the element.

`box-shadow: 3px -3px 3px 0 #999` creates a shadow that has an offset of 3px to the *right* and 3px *up* from the top, so the shadow will show on the *right* and *top* sides of the element.

Because these two shadows are combined (overlapping), you will see shadows on the *top*, *right* and *bottom* sides of the element, but not the *left*.

### Variations

Of course, there are many different shadow combinations, but the 4 basic variations of this example are:

```
box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 0 #999, -3px 3px 3px 0 #999;  /* No shadow on the top */
box-shadow: -3px 3px 3px 0 #999, -3px -3px 3px 0 #999;  /* No shadow on the right */
box-shadow: 3px -3px 3px 0 #999, -3px -3px 3px 0 #999;  /* No shadow on the bottom */
box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 0 #999, 3px -3px 3px 0 #999;  /* No shadow on the left */
```

Comment: Thanks man..this worked! but still i didnt get an idea how it works like where to give this negative sign to remove one sides and all.

Comment: You really need to play around with the `box-shadow` property and its 'offset-x` and `offset-y` values to understand why it works - best way is through experimentation. I'll add something to the answer though.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Well explained great answer.

Comment: No problem, glad it has helped!